# How to avoid side-scrolling by a floating div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div with absolute position floating on the right side (green).
It is correct that protrudes half
The problem is when the window to the minimum size of 985px page is reduced. Although the div is floating generates side-scrolling, is it possible to avoid this by reducing the window scroll?

[image]

```
<body style="width:100%; min-width: 985px; padding:0px; margin:0px; color:#FFFFFF; background:#160E30; border:2px solid yellow;">
<div style="position:relative; width:985px; margin:0 auto; height:70px; border:2px solid #FFFFFF">
    <div style="color:#FFFFFF">TITLE</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:-10px; right:-15px; width:100px; height:30px; border:2px solid green;">FLOAT</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sb8c216s/4/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/sb8c216s/4/show/

It's a small picture by simply design. Half of the image is within the page and the rest outside. When the window is reduced to the minimum width of the body, half of the image is not hidden, shown full generating a small scroll.

Comment: You don't want to be able to scroll horizontally?

Comment: Is this for a design motif (e.g. a ribbon edge or some other element with no other purpose than styling)?  If it is, I would suggest a pseudo-element.  When absolutely positioned, they don't cause overflow scrollbars.

Comment: Yes, It's a small picture by simply design. Half of the image is within the page and the rest outside. When the window is reduced to the minimum width of the body, half of the image is not hidden, shown full generating a small scroll.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I tried with the pseudo-element but still occurs after scroll.

Comment: @ephramd It seems you are correct.  I'm not sure if something changed or not, but the effect I was talking about can be seen if you switch sides for the pseudo-element (left vs right).  The scroll bar does not appear for me under those conditions in Chrome on Mac.  I can only assume that the best option left is `overflow:hidden` on some wrapping element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

- Body tag has overflow:auto property provided
- Container element has overflow: hidden
- 'Left' and 'Right' elements are moved within the 'main' div container

https://wordimpress.com/how-to-position-elements-to-the-negative-right-position-and-prevent-horizontal-scrollbars/

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem correctly, the problem is `width: 100%` on the `body` tag. Remove this and it will remove the scroll bars.

This happened because you have a border applied. `width: 100%` will make the element the full size if the parent element (in this case the entire document window). Then border is added which makes the element bigger than the document window.

This is normal behaviour based on the "box model"
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

The `body` tag is a `block level` element which means that it will take up the full width of it's parent element unless told otherwise. The default setting for the width attribute is `auto` which means it will automatically reduce the width so that the entire element (width/padding/border/margin) will fit without increasing the size of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the extra space taken by the borders. Add **box-sizing: border-box;** to body css. It will solve your problem.